# How does @inject of Mobx map stores?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

In Mobx (mobx-react), we can 'inject' stores in a React component like this:

```
@inject('store')
@observer class Abc extends React.Component {

}
```

This results in `Abc` getting `store` as a `prop` like `this.props.store`.
But how does `inject` map `store` to an actual store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You registered it first by passing them as props to the Provider:

```
<Provider store1={} store2={}>
    <Abc />
</Provider>
```

So the Provider component adds the props that were passed to the Provider Component to react's context. React's Context now automatically passes these props to every component.

The only thing that inject does is, to read the stores object from the context, take the strings you passed in, filter the stores object by your string arguments and pass it to your component.

As you can see, mobxStores is the variable that holds your store objects.

You could also not use the @inject at all and access your stores in your components like this:

```
this.context.mobxStores.YOUR_STORE_NAME
```

**Here is the code:**

- https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/master/src/Provider.js
- https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/master/src/inject.js

Answer (score 0):

Mobx has a Provider which you can use to pass the stores to the component.
Provider is used to put the dependencies on react's context.

```
const yourStore = new YourStore();
const app = (
  <Provider yourStore={yourStore}>
    <Abc />
  </Provider>  
);
ReactDom.render(app, container);
```

Now  your component Abc will have access to the store as this.props.yourStore

Comment: So you are saying that `@inject('xyz')` will internally call `<Provider xyz={xyz}/>`? If yes then where should the `Provider` and instance of `xyz` be defined?

Comment: No you have to explicitly set the Provider in your code. https://medium.com/dailyjs/mobx-react-best-practices-17e01cec4140 has more explanation. Also you can see in this project https://github.com/rwieruch/favesound-mobx/blob/1e9762d2f3dc369a5b15bcdd2dfd65ee82a38390/src/index.js how they inject the Provider for all the stores initially.